# what are the implications of setting up a subscriber as a publisher?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

We have application database (APP_DB) that creates a "live copy" of itself via transactional replication (push) to a database (COPY_DB) on a separate server.  This COPY_DB is used for reporting and troubleshooting.

There is now a need for a small subset of the tables (4 tables out of 150) to be placed ("live") in a second database (NEW_DB).  What would be the implications of setting up COPY_DB as a publisher of these four tables to subscriber NEW_DB?  Good idea?  Horrible idea?

It seems like a silly idea to me, but I find myself in a situation where I have more control over the server where COPY_DB and NEW_DB live and could more easily implement such a solution rather than setting up a second publication on APP_DB.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the republishing model.  It is usually used for balancing distribution loads over slow or expensive links although I have seen it used in the scenario you described as well.  The republishing topology you propose is supported which can be found near the bottom of the page [Republish Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152553.aspx), Transactional publication -> Transactional subscription/transactional publication -> Transactional subscription.

If I recall correctly, the challenge with this topology occurs if you ever have to reinitialize COPY_DB, you will also have to reinitialize NEW_DB.